# Spring-Boot: Running an unpacked jar and starting it with java -cp <classpath> <mainclass>

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a *HelloWorld* project of *Spring-Boot*. I created jar file of the project using this command:

```
mvn package
```

I can run the unpacked jar file using this command:

```
java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

---

But when I want to use the following command to start it:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\User\Desktop\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

I get `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
> at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13) Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> ... 1 more

I also aware of this note in Spring-Boot documentaion:

> This is why we recommend that you always launch unpacked jars using
> java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher. This will initialize
> the application.* banner variables before building the classpath and
> launching your app.

---

**But what is the correct form of the command `java -cp <classpath> <mainclass>` to run an Spring-Boot project using command line?**

Comment: You will need to add all the jars that are required to the classpath. You only added the root directory not the actual jar files.

Comment: The *classpath.idx* file inside *BOOT-INF* directory declared all dependencies and jar files. I have not defined it manually It's an standard Spring package. @M.Deinum

Comment: The `classpath.idx` has nothing to do with the java classpath, it doesn't know anything about that file, that is a spring specific thing.